# Meteor - Rest API in existing project using iron:router - html sent?

Tags: api, rest, meteor

I have an existing project that serves a webapp. I want to add a REST webservice to get data in and out.

some code:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});


Router.map(function() {
    this.route('GeolocationBGRoute', {
        path: '/api/v1/geolocation/',
        where: 'server',
        layout: null,
        action: function () {
            // GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
            var requestMethod = this.request.method;
            // Data from a POST request
            var requestData = this.request.body;

            // log stuff
            console.log('GeolocationBG post: ' + requestMethod);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(requestData));

            // TODO: security/validation
            //  require some security with data
            //  validate userId/uuid/etc (inside Meteor.call?)

            // Can insert into a Collection from the server (or whatever)
            if (GeolocationLog.insert(requestData)) {
                this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                this.response.end('ok');
                return;
            }

            // if we end up with an error case, you can return 500
            this.response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            this.response.end('failure');
        }
    });
});
```

When I call this page with

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data '{"foo":"bar"}' 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/geolocation'
```

I get all the HTML back from the `layoutTemplate: 'layout'` - how can I just make a raw restful API which just returns JSON without the HTML of the existing project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `Router.configure` only on the client - either in a file under the `client` directory, or guard that section with an `if (Meteor.isClient)`.

I like to keep my routes in a shared directory, but I define all of the controllers and front-end configuration stuff on the client.

Comment: Thanks. You got me on the right path - I created a new routes-api.js file in /server and put all the API stuff there. Cheers!